# Complications from drafting human breeding stock

Tags: society, humans, politics, ancient-history, sex

We all know about the various obsessions of the kings from olde times... Some women liked bathing in the blood of virgins, well ex virgins after watching them being raped by guards and animals...some men were obsessed with tall guys and some drank heavy metals or fought wars for the thrill of it.

It's not unheard of people in power doing strange stuff.

This one king in my story is planning on drafting a lot of people from far regions for breeding purposes, to mix the blood in the population.

What non economical social complications could arise from bringing by force human stock from other regions and making them create offspring with the native population and how would a king prevent them?

The kingdom is rich, not a real economy, the king owns all the land, if you use the land you must pay for it with your work.

The king owns different unrelated armies of mercenaries and soldiers for pay, just to avoid the old problem where the military goes against the Caesar, if one army goes disloyal, there's plenty that might have might be willing to eliminate them and get their pay.

Laws are loose, almost everything is permitted except:

- dishonesty
- murder
- rape (being dishonest to get laid counts as rape)
- urinating and defecating on the floor in populated zones or in water sources
- vandalism
- slacking off, everyone is obligated by law to learn to farm, hunt and wave cloth, metallic wire and baskets and the art of courting a woman for men.
- slavery is not permitted, if you want free servants, have children like all the civilised people!

The kingdom is huge for it's time, counting 12 million people, it doesn't cover a large area and it's all packed in like an ancient Beijing ...well the modern Beijing but in ancient times.

The people are brought by force, and once they are inside the kingdom they are using the land and therefore they must pay, they could leave obviously....and die trying while getting lost at sea or frozen if they leave by the mountains. So they are obligated to stay.

Comment: All kinds of complications could arise from bringing lots of people from other regions. A wise king may avert some of them, but most likely not all -- I seem to remeber that even a few allmighty Ottoman sultans were deposed by revolted janissaries, and the janissaries were technically not even allowed to marry. On the other hand, all kinds of good things could arise from bringing lots of people from other regions -- aren't cities such as New York and London rich and thriving? Are you by any chance trying to con(vince) volunteers to invent the plot of the story for you free of charge?

Comment: Plenty of social problems 'might' (conceivably) arise (which doesn't mean they will), perhaps even a few economic ones if the numbers are high enough, but from your wording it seems to me your after genetic ones, there are none, other than a few things like sickle cell (which is actually an advantage in the right conditions), in the greater scheme of things it's only ever a good thing to bring in 'fresh blood'.

Comment: Very annoyed foreign Kings wanting their people back and willing to wage war to get them? Payment? Can you clarify what area of concerns you might want to focus on, it's very broad at present.

Comment: This is the tiniest kernel of a potentially very interesting query! I for one appreciate the atmosphere setting introduction, however I really do not at all appreciate that your question doesn't give any detail on the cultural or religious or historical background that might lead to this situation, doesn't focus on one relatively narrow subset of complications, and doesn't provide  any criteria for helping us give a good answer. Am voting to close (VTC) until you can clean your question up!

Comment: I am a bit confused by your wording. Are you breeding humans like animals? What is the social, economical, and political status of 'human stock' brought for breeding?

Comment: @Otkin humans are assets - sigma male ...

Comment: I am not sure I get your reference. But it does not seem to answer my questions.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @user88823  The question says:  " Some women liked bathing in the blood of virgins, well ex virgins after watching them being raped by guards and animals"  At the moment I can think of only one women was convicted of bathing in the blood of women and girls and so was probably guilty of it.  Can you think of any other examples to justify the word "some", and/or even a single woman who satisfied all of the parts of your statement?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the problems of disease, which may plague either the imported population or the local population, or both, there are a number of other problems.

This situation is not greatly different to historical slavery between Africa and the Americas, where Africans were imported by force to the Americas.  While the purpose of this human traffic was for purposes of cheap labor, the problems of importing humans for reproductive purposes will have many of the same problems.

Firstly, if this traffic in humans is non-consensual, it is slavery, even if the purpose is reproductive rather than for labor.  This will result in these sex slaves becoming an underclass with whom the local population will be resistant toward intimate interaction, and many such interactions will be rape, even if such interactions are legal.  Then, the resultant mixed-race children will also be seen as an underclass.

This may be mitigated by recruiting volunteers from the source population.  It will probably be necessary to offer financial or other incentives to the recruits.  The immigrant recruits would need to have legal equality with the indigenous population.

However, history has shown that even when migrants are legally equal to the locals, the migrants tend to form insular communities that do not readily intermarry with the locals.  To mitigate this, one of two strategies may be used:

1. recruit only one gender, probably males.  Males are more able to rapidly impregnate several women, increasing the rate at which new genes are spread through the population.

Or

2. Recruit only unattached individuals of both genders, and segregate them to different regions of the destination nation, so that male and female recruits may not readily intermarry, and must therefore intermarry with the locals.  While this will likely result in more recruits, unless the recruits are forbidden to migrate within the destination country, there is still the possibility that some will intermarry within their own group.

Secondly, humans tend to be xenophobic, preferring to intermarry within their own societal and linguistic groups.  The foreign, different racial group being recruited would tend to be considered inferior due to their lower numbers.

In order to mitigate these barriers to the desired racial mixing, there are several strategies that may be used:

1. Recruit individuals with valuable, high-status skills, or the capability of learning them, or who are wealthy in their own right.  Wealth, or the capability to become wealthy would make these individuals more attractive to local members of the opposite sex, though already wealthy individuals would be harder to recruit.
2. Provide financial incentives for interracial unions resulting in the birth of mixed-race children where one parent is a member of the local indigenous race and the other is an immigrant or a first or second generation mixed-race individual, with the incentive paid out to both parents for the first child only of any pairing, possibly whether married or not.  This would tend to encourage each recruit to have children with as many locals as possible, thus increasing the genetic diversity of the population.
3. Institute a campaign of education and propaganda encouraging multiculturalism and racial integration.
4. Criminalize racist or hate-related communication and impose harsher penalties for hate-related crimes.
5. The nation's leaders, celebrities and their children should be encouraged by whatever means necessary to take partners from the other racial group wherever possible, encouraging others to do the same by example and reducing the stigma of interracial unions.
6. Religion or a person's status as a religious leader should not be an exemption from the measures taken to encourage these policies.  If necessary and not already enacted, a legal separation of church and state should be implemented before the policies of racial integration are instituted.  Where possible, clergy in favour of these policies should be assisted to gain higher ecclesiastical rank.

Answer (score 0):

**Disease.**

Syphilis is said to have been brought to Europe by Christopher Columbus.  He and is crew contracted the disease from the natives they encountered.

[A Brief History of Syphilis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3956094/)

> The Columbian hypothesis. This very popular hypothesis states that the
> navigators in Columbus fleet would have brought the affliction on
> their return form the New World in 1493 [3,12]. This theory is
> supported by documents belonging to Fernandez de Oviedo and Ruy Diaz
> de Isla, two physicians with Spanish origins who were present at the
> moment when Christopher Columbus returned from America. The former,
> sent by King Ferdinand of Spain in the New World, confirms that the
> disease he had encountered for the first time in Europe was familiar
> at that time to the indigenes who had already developed elaborated
> treatment methods. As for Ruy Diaz de Isla, the physician acknowledges
> syphilis as an “unknown disease, so far not seen and never
> described”.... Ruy Diaz de Isla is also the one that states in a
> manuscript that Pinzon de Palos, the pilot of Columbus, and also other
> members of the crew already suffered from syphilis on their return
> from the New World [10,12].

Of course the foreigners brought in as breeding stock might have any number of diseases endemic among those foreign populations but new to the country where they are brought.  I like the idea of special body lice to which the breeders have some immunity, but not the people in the new country.

--

The king could do some to prevent something like epidemic lice by quarantining the newcomers for a period, perhaps on an island along with persons from the kingdom (preferably the crew that brought the foreigners).   If the persons from his kingdom fall ill because of living or traveling with the foreigners (like Columbus' crew were ill with syphilis), the foreigners should be given nice presents and brought back to their country.  Along with the sick crew who will be invited to not come back.

Comment: @Pelinore - how about the Nepalese bringing cholera to Haiti?  https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/08/18/490468640/u-n-admits-role-in-haiti-cholera-outbreak-that-has-killed-thousands     There are lots of examples of foreign folks bringing diseases to new lands.

Comment: Fair enough // just seems to me any disease will just as easily propagate through contact (trade & exploration) without any movement of populations involved so may not be entirely relevant on the grounds 'it will happen anyway' even without any migration // it's not an area I've put any reading into though so just a gut reaction as it were, just ignore me & carry on ;)